# The name of dynamic property was already used as the declared property name of open type

Tags: c#, odata

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

OData automatically produces the following JSON output where it puts the JSON properties on the entity level instead:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"http://localhost/odata/$metadata#Items",
    "value":[
        {
            "Id":1,
            "Setting1":"Value",
            "Setting2":10
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want this because my JSON could potentially have a property with the same name which will result in the error: The name of dynamic property 'Id' was already used as the declared property name of open type.

How can I disable the automatic mapping to an open type that OData does?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/walkthrough-simple-object-model-and-query-csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a separate entity. This returns the desired result.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public OpenType Settings { get; set; }
}

public class OpenType
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Settings { get; set; }
}
```